# AC Resonances - Reduction In power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity

I am having trouble understanding the following;

> Because the Q value is based on the bandwidth at the 3dB points in the frequency transfer function, we need to find a way to measure these. In our case we can measure voltage (using the oscilloscope), but not (as easily) power. There is, however, a simple relationship between voltage and power, $P = \frac{v^{2}}{R}$. if you assume the same R value for both $P_{in}$ and $P_{out}$, it is easy to show that for voltages, the 3dB
>   point corresponds to a reduction in amplitude by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

I know that $[db] \equiv 10 log_{10}(P)$ but I don't understand how I can show this reduction in amplitude.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a power ratio of a 1/2, we have

$$10 \log \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} = 10 \log \frac{1}{2} = -3.0\,\mathrm {dB}$$

But, for a resistor, power is proportional to the voltage squared

$$P = \frac{v^2}{R}$$

thus (assuming $R_{in} = R_{out}$)$^*$

$$10 \log \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} = 10 \log \frac{v^2_{out}}{v^2_{in}} = 20 \log \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}$$

Can you take it from here?

---

$^*$ In the case that $R_{in} \ne R_{out}$, we have

$$10 \log \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}} = 10 \log \left(\frac{v^2_{out}}{v^2_{in}}\frac{R_{in}}{R_{out}}\right) $$

Comment: Yes, thanks so much!

By bringing the exponent down you arrive at $20 log \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}} = -3dB$

$\frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}} = 10^{\frac{-3}{20}} = 0.707... \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$